# How to filter an object by specific string

Tags: angular, object

I want to filter an array using a string value ( display only the rows that contents this string or part of it ).

for exemple I have that object:

```
0: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "1043 TU 147", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2, …}
1: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5076 TU 162", FullName2: "", FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2, …}
2: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
3: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
4: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5217 TU 185", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2, …}
```

Rq: this is just an example.

for that I have now "test" as a string and the result should be:

```
2: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
3: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
```

because "test ET7" and "test analog" has the string "test".

also I need to test every columns and fields here for example if I have that object:

```
0: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
1: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
2: {CurrentDriverElement: "test LA ", FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
    3: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
    4: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5217 TU 185", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2, …}
```

and here U found as result:

```
 0: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
    1: {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
    2: {CurrentDriverElement: "test LA ", FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1, …}
```

Comment: `yourArr.filter(item => item.FullName.includes('test'))`

Comment: the `test` could be only in FullName field or in any other fields?

Comment: in all fields of obejct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter()`

```
let result = arrayData.filter(item => item.FullName.includes('test') || item.FullName2.includes('test'));
```

Comment: thanks but I need to test all fields not just Fullname field

Comment: you can use the `||` method for multiple conditions. I've updated the answer.

Comment: there are edge cases like `CurrentDriverElement` that could be **null** - there so `item.CurrentDriverElement.includes` will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

array.filter(item => item.FullName.includes('test'));

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, you can use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
let result = arr.filter(f=> f.FullName.indexOf('test'))
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "1043 TU 147", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2 },
    {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5076 TU 162", FullName2: "", FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2 },
    {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1},
    {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1},
    {CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5217 TU 185", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2}
];

let result = arr.filter(f=> f.FullName.indexOf('test'))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing all fields you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) that will return all values

```js
[{CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "1043 TU 147", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2},
{CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5076 TU 162", FullName2: "", FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2},
{CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test ET7 mycom ", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1},
{CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "test analog", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: -1},
{CurrentDriverElement: null, FullName: "5217 TU 185", FullName2: null, FuelTheoreticalCosumptionAvg: 0, FuelTypeEnum: 2}].filter(e => {
return Object.values(e).some(value => /test/.test(value))
})
```

I think that Regexp is cleaner solution than something like:

```js
[].filter(e => {
return Object.values(e).some(value => value && typeof value.includes === 'function' &&  value.includes('test'))
})
```

as **value** could be **null**, **undefined** or **number** - so you have to test if value exists and if there is possible to call `includes` method on that value